# Visual Studio 2010 Pro - Run as Administrator no network drives

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, administrator, mapped-drive

When i run VS 2010 as Administrator then VS can't find my mapped network drive where my sourcecode is located.

But i realy need VS to run as an administrator in order to attach to a process.

Anyone got experience with this issue?

Comment: Well, your mapped network drives are mapped in a non-elevated user context. Your VS2010 process is running in an elevated administrative context. Thus it probably wouldn't have the saved credentials for your mapped network drives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redo the mapping while running as admin. Or use UNC path instead of mapped drives.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I'm running inside Parallels on a mac, and for whatever reason Visual Studio won't see the shared drives in elevated mode, while Explorer in elevated mode can...  grr.  (ps.  Hi Kate!)

Comment: Me too. Perfectly the same situation: mac + parallel + Visual Studio with high privilege.  
have you resolved?!?

Comment: Same situation MAC + Parallel + Visual Studio (ADMIN)

Comment: Same situation here :(